# for loop with more than 2 variable

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to use more than 2 variable in a for loop.

i tried this

```
for(integer j=0, k=1; j<iSize.size(); j++, k++) {
}
```

and getting this error 
Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found ',' at line 188 column 53

Please help me to find the solution. 
Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in this case since there is only one condition to end the loop you could write the following:

```
integer k = 1;
for (integer j=0; j < iSize.size(); j++)
{
    k++;
    //Code goes here
}
```

if you actually needed two loops you could do

```
for (integer j=0; j < iSize.size(); j++)
{
    for (integer k = 1; k < Some_Condition; k++)
    {
         //Code goes here
    }
}
```

Following either of these suggestions should clear up that error.  [Edit] The code you have now is in an incorrect format and the compiler is expecting the closing paren since you can only put 1 statement at the end of the for loop and you have 2.